# Creating and "Relating" variables with eachother, with tags from influxdb measurement on Grafana 10

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-variable, grafana-templating, flux-influxdb

I am creating filter variables on Grafana 10 from influxdb 2.7.4 with below code. Each variable seperately.

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

schema.tagValues(
bucket: "Vbuck",
tag: "Service_Name"
)
```

**But i need to create variables depend on other variables.**

*For example :*

*I have Service_Name, Owner_Group, Group_Manager tags.
I have GroupManager and OwnerGroup variables.
Service_Name is dependent to Group_Manager.
Group_Manager is dependent to Owner_Group.
When i choose Owner_Group in filter variables. The Group_Managers should be listed dependent to related Owner_Group. And when Group_Manager is selected Service_Names dependet to related Group_Manager should be listed in Service_Names variable list.*

In old influxdb version i was creating **"Service_Name Variable"** with below query in influxdb 1.8 with influxql :

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "SELECTBOX_VALUES" WITH KEY = "Service_Name" where "Group_Manager"=~ /^$GroupManager$/ and "Owner_Group"=~ /^$OwnerGroup$/
```

Now how can i do same in v2.7.4?
I should relate variables with eachother.
So that when owner group is choosen, the groupmanagers will be listed just for this ownergroup and service names will be listed for just choosen owner group and choosen manager.